# How to input Reynolds number and Mach number as input boundary conditions in Ansys Fluent

Tags: cfd

I am trying to validate the pressure distribution and drag polars of some basic aerofoils using Ansys Fluent however the only conditions given are the freestream Mach number (0.735) and Reynolds number (6000000). I am modelling the external flow around the aerofoil in Ansys and therefore am trying to resolve this in a way that can be input into Ansys, for example would it be most appropriate to use intensity and hydraulic diameter and how so?

Comment: Voting to keep the question open, it is about aircraft aerodynamics and has attracted a good answer

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for product support, not for aerodynamics insight. and the only answer it got says (paraphrasing) "I don't know about this numerical solution, you just need to solve the Navier-Stokes equations" that is definitely NOT what OP asked about.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not familiar with ANSYS, so this is just [plain physics](https://durhamcollege.ca/wp-content/uploads/Thermodynamics-Basic-Concepts.pdf).

You need three parameters to describe flow conditions:

- air speed
- air density at rest
- air temperature at rest

then all other parameters can be determined from those three. Take air pressure for example: It is density times temperature and a constant which for air is $R$ = 287.085 J/kg·K.

To arrive at the desired Mach number, you need to know the speed of sound at the given atmospheric conditions. So you need to determine a temperature $T$; once you have this, the rest is straightforward:
$$\text{speed of sound  }a = \sqrt{\kappa\cdot R\cdot T}$$
$\kappa$ is the [ratio of specific heats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) and for a diatomic gas at room temperature is 1.405. So lets pick 20°C ([which makes $T$ = 293.15K](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=room%20temperature)) and plug in the numbers: $a^2$ = 1.405·287.085·293.15 = 118,243 and $a$ = 343.8 m/s. For Mach 0.735 your flow speed at infinity must be 252.471 m/s.

The Reynolds number now gives you the size of your airfoil. When we know the gas (air) and the temperature, we can [look up](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-absolute-kinematic-viscosity-d_601.html?vA=20&units=C#) the [kinematic viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Kinematic_viscosity) $\nu$ = 0.0000156 m²/s. Now, with Re = 6,000,000 given, we can solve for the length $l$: $l$ = 0.0000156·6,000,000 / 252.471 = 0.37 m. That should be the chord length of your airfoil to hit the desired Reynolds number.

For different temperatures or gasses you only need to use other numbers, but the process is the same.

Comment: Strange - I correct a glaring mistake in the answer and get an unexplained downvote as a consequence. Should I leave flawed answers stand?